# EmberCLI - File change detection stopped working - where to look?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm using EmberCLI to build an ember app and out of the blue live reloading has stopped working. Terminal also isn't telling me that a file has changed, so the file-changes aren't detected. How would I debug such a thing? What could be wrong?

Comment: What version of ember-cli are you using?

Comment: EmberCLI 0.1.2, `--watcher=polling` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If your on a mac and using sublime as a text editor it is likely this issue, there are some workarounds in the ticket:

https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2226

Comment: Got me in the right direction, I didn't have any errors in console though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the exact error was, but using `--watcher=polling` fixed it. I guess it has something to do with `Sane` and `EMFILE`.

```
# Start the application with:

ember serve --watcher=polling
```

https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/974